# Real distance (Walking) from 2 points in Google maps for Android v2 (Results seems unaccurated)

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I have used Google Maps v2 API in Android.

I need to find a real walking distance from point A to point B.
I have used Location.distanceTo() and Location.distanceBetween(), but when I compare the results with Google Maps on website, it is different.

For example, location methods return 400 meters from Point A to B and Google Maps on web returns 1 km.

How to solve ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

`distanceBetween()` calculates a "straight-line" distance between the two points.

(AFAIK it is really a great circle calculation, but for walking distances the difference won't matter)

There is nothing in the Android SDK or Google Play Services SDK that will tell you the distance between two points by walking, driving, mass transit, [machine gun jetpack](https://what-if.xkcd.com/21/), or any other mode of transportation. It is possible that there is a Web service that can give you this information.